# Count on left join querty

Tags: sql, mariadb

Just help me with this query please.

```
SELECT COUNT (name.IN) AS Total, name.St_Name, name.Class_Id,
    teacher.Class_Id
  FROM name
  Left Join teacher ON  name.Class_Id = teacher.Class_Id
  WHERE name.IN = '1';
```

**Question** : how do I `COUNT(name.IN)` as total and get the number of students that `name.Class_Id` and `teacher.Class_Id` are the same.

Comment: The table `name` contains students actually? Why is it called `name` then? And a student (name) is associated with one single class (`name.class_id`)? And what is `in`? What does it represent? Obviously it's some string column that contains numbers (such as `'1'`). But what meaning does it have? Is this a unique column (the primary key maybe) for the table? Or can there be multiple `name` records for `in = '1'`? You are outer joining `teacher` because there are classes without a teacher? Strange. And you want to count what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an aggregation function like COUNT or SUM or MAX?

Then when you add other fields to the SELECT, then those fields should be in the GROUP BY.

This is true for most databases. But [MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) can be an exception to that SQL92 rule.
In [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/group-by/) it's not permitted to omit those fields from the GROUP BY if the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` [SQL_MODE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql-mode/) is used.

So try this:

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(name.IN) AS Total,
 COUNT(DISTINCT name.St_Name) AS TotalUniqueStudentNames, 
 COUNT(teacher.Class_id) AS TotalMatchingTeacherClass,
 name.Class_Id
FROM name
LEFT JOIN teacher ON name.Class_Id = teacher.Class_id
WHERE name.IN = '1'
GROUP BY name.Class_Id
ORDER BY name.Class_Id
```

Comment: Thank you so Much!

Answer (score 1):

A SELECT statement clause that divides the query result into groups of rows, usually for the purpose of performing one or more aggregations on each group. The SELECT statement returns one row per group

```
    SELECT (name.IN) AS Total, name.St_Name, name.Class_Id, teacher.Class_Id
        FROM name
        Left Join teacher ON  name.Class_Id = teacher.Class_Id
        WHERE name.IN = '1'
group by  name.St_Name, name.Class_Id, teacher.Class_Id
```